# Cast dynamic to specific type

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am retrieving JSON with different object type in one part.
I made this part as dynamic.

I need to get data from this object so I created class which looks the same as the dynamic data like below:

```
public class SpecificObject1
{
    public string Title{get; set;}
    public object[] ViewElements{get; set}
    public object AnyAttributes{get; set;}
}
```

Here is how I want to convert it to this specific object:

```
  var @switch = new Dictionary<Type, Action> {
                { typeof(x), () =>  jsonObj.Some = jsonObj.Some as SpecificObject1},
                { typeof(y), () =>  ......}
            };
```

Casting with `as` returns null.

EDIT:
Changed properties to real one

dynamic contains:

```
AnyAttributes: {object}
Title: "title"
ViewElements: object[0]
```

Comment: what is the content of `jsonObj.Some`?

Answer (score 7):

You can´t change the type of an object - be it `dynamic` or any other compile-time type. Thus even if you assign `jsonObj.Some as SpecificObject1` to `jsonObj.Some` you can´t change its *compiletime* type (probably `dynamic` in your case which *is* a compiletime-type).

This would imply you could to this:

```
int a = 3;
a = a as string;
```

Which is obvious non-sense. `a` is of type `int` which can´t be changed. So even if you *could cast `a` to a `string` you can´t assign the result (which would be of type `sting`)  to `a` because `a` actually is of type `int`.

The same applies to an instance of `dynamic`:

```
dynamic b = a as Bar;
```

This will still evaluate to `b` being of type `dynamic`. However if `a` was a `Bar`-instance before, the runtime-type of `b` surely is `Bar` as well. Anyway you don´t get anything by this cast as the *compile-time-type* of `b` is still `dynamic` - making it a no-op.

EDIT: In order to get a compile-time type which you can use you have to create a new instance of `SpecificType` based on `jsonObj.Some`:

```
var newValue = new SpecificObject {
    Title = jsonObj.Some.Title,
    ViewElements = jsonObj.Some.ViewElements,
    AnyAttributes = jsonObj.Some.AnyAttributes 
}
```

However you can´t assign this to `jsonObj.Some` and expect the latter to be of type `SpecificObject` at compile-time. Anyway as it already is `dynamic` you can do everything you want with it, for instance set its `Title`:

```
jsonObj.Some.Title = "NewTitle";
```

You won´t need any cast for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Slapper.AutoMapper functionality. Use MapDynamic() method for your needs.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

[Test]
public void Can_Map_Matching_Field_Names_Using_Dynamic()
{
    // Arrange
    dynamic dynamicPerson = new ExpandoObject();
    dynamicPerson.Id = 1;
    dynamicPerson.FirstName = "Clark";
    dynamicPerson.LastName = "Kent";

    // Act
    var person = Slapper.AutoMapper.MapDynamic<Person>( dynamicPerson ) as Person;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull( person );
    Assert.That( person.Id == 1 );
    Assert.That( person.FirstName == "Clark" );
    Assert.That( person.LastName == "Kent" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to Slapper.Automapper. Hint: There is even a prerelease on NuGet for .NET Standard ([#44](https://github.com/SlapperAutoMapper/Slapper.AutoMapper/issues/44)).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `as` for casting, it Assigns `null` to the destination if the source is null or it is not convertible. So you cannot use it with value types. Where as this(`jsonObj.Some = (SpecificObject1)jsonObj.Some`) will throws [`InvalidCastException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception) if either source is null or not convertible.

```
var @switch = new Dictionary<Type, Action> {
                { typeof(x), () =>  jsonObj.Some = (SpecificObject1)jsonObj.Some },
                { typeof(y), () =>  ......}
            };
```

Comment: throws exception I chacked again and properties are the same ;(

Comment: @miechooy : which means `either source is null or not convertible.`